# sqlite difference between rows

Tags: sqlite, string-comparison, set-difference

In SQLite I have a collection of records and I want to only show the records with specific differences.

The table has something like the following values:

`file  | idx   | values
------|-------|----------------------
1     | 101   | 1,3,7,11,23,11
2     | 101   | 1,3,7,11,23,11
3     | 101   | 0,4,8,60,20,11
1     | 211   | 12,11,23
2     | 211   | 12,0,23
3     | 211   | 12,0,23
1     | 300   | 1
2     | 300   | 0
3     | 300   | 0`

I want to be able to select two different fileIDs, and compare them.
I mean, I want to examine only records with `(file = 1 AND file = 2)`

What I cant to get back as a result is a collection of records that are not the same:

`file  | idx   | values
------|-------|----------------------
1     | 211   | 12,11,23
2     | 211   | 12,0,23
1     | 300   | 1
2     | 300   | 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you do not want rows for which another row with the same `idx` and `values` values exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE file IN (1, 2)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM MyTable AS T2
                  WHERE file IN (1, 2)
                    AND file   <> MyTable.file
                    AND idx    =  MyTable.idx
                    AND values =  MyTable.values);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recieved an answer in another forum. This seems to work:

`select * from  thetable a, thetable b
    where a.file <> b.file and a.idx = b.idx and a.values <> b.values and
      a.file in (1, 2) and b.file in (1, 2);`

Of course I change certain values as variables in a prepared statement. But it did the trick